# Sharing a story to Instagram with a background image and a sticker - IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, share, url-scheme

I'm trying to share a story with a background image a a sticker image via URL Scheme on my ios app, i am using the attached code and it dose not work.
When i'm trying to share just a background image or just a sticker it does work. But when im trying share both a background image and a sticker in top of it, it dose not work.

Any Ideas?

```
func shareToInstagram(deepLinkString : String){
        let url = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share")!
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){

            let backgroundData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "shop_placeholder")!, 1.0)!
            let creditCardImage = UIImage(named: "share_instagram")!
            let stickerData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(creditCardImage)!
            let pasteBoardItems = [
                                    ["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage" : backgroundData],
                                    ["com.instagram.sharedSticker.stickerImage" : stickerData],
                                  ]

            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

                UIPasteboard.general.setItems(pasteBoardItems, options: [.expirationDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)])
            } else {
                UIPasteboard.general.items = pasteBoardItems
            }
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

I copy pasted OP's code for use in my own app (only substituting different UIImages) and found only 1 issue, pasteboard items should be contained in a single array otherwise instagram will render only the first item (in this case the background layer).  To fix this, replace the declaration of pasteboard items with the following code

```
let pasteBoardItems = [
                ["com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage" : backgroundData,
                "com.instagram.sharedSticker.stickerImage" : stickerData]
            ]
```

(basically just remove the close and open bracket separating the two items)

Also as a previous answer stated, make sure "instagram-stories" is included in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in the info.plist file

I use this exact code in my app and it now works perfect

Comment: yes, the issue is in the bracket `[[ "com...": ... , "com...": ... , etc... ]]`

Answer (score 3):

Everything is correct, my code is similar and it works for iOS 11+. I suggest you the following:

1. check the image data you pass to pasteboard (jpg can't be converted with
   `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and vice versa)
2. check the info.plist. You should enable "instagram-stories" scheme in it (`LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key)

Answer (score 0):

1. Like Alec said, you need to put all of Instagram data in one list, not multiple lists. look at the example from the [meta documents](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/):

```
NSArray *pasteboardItems = @[@{@"com.instagram.sharedSticker.stickerImage" : stickerImage,
                               @"com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundTopColor" : backgroundTopColor,
                               @"com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundBottomColor" : backgroundBottomColor}];
```

2. For more recent readers, as of [swift 4.2 and iOS 12](https://github.com/alexliubj/Swift-Migration-4.2-iOS-12)     UIImageJPEGRepresentation is replaced by jpegData. change

```
let backgroundData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0)
```

with

```
let backgroundData = yourImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
```